# "Suit yourself" as an answer to "How are you?"

Tags: phrase-usage

A colleague of mine who works in a company told me that his colleagues and bosses will answer, every time he asks "how are you?" or "how is it going?", "good, suit yourself".

Does anybody know why they might be answering in this way?

Comment: I'm guessing he's mishearing it.  Likely it's something along the lines of "Good, and how 'bout yourself?"

Comment: Is it a clothing company?